# Kotlin extension functions - completion?

Tags: kotlin, definition, completion

I have watched a few tutorials on learning Kotlin, and I am confused as to the meaning of the word 'completion' as used in the quote below.  The speaker is a developer at JetBrains, and this is taken from a transcript (not youtube subtitles):

> Here, we define an extension function to string called lastChar, and
> we can use it as a member function. It's visible in completion, so it
> can be easily discovered. It's like a regular utility function defined
> outside of the class. But on the other hand, thanks to completion, it
> can be easily found and used like it was a member.

What is the meaning of the word completion in this usage?

Thank you.

Comment: Completion means the suggestions to complete the code you're typing given by the IDE. so, if there's a function called `getData`, and you type get, getData will be shown in the list of code completion appears below the cursor to quickly complete your code. For example - [see this image](https://imgur.com/a/tAFehnS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you type `.` after an object, you can see all its member and extension functions and properties in the auto-completion box. Their point is that an extension makes this possible for what would otherwise be a utility function that you would have to remember by name.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, I thought that might have been the answer to the first mention - but it did not seem to me that "thanks to completion" would be talking about the IDE, because the course did not mention a specific IDE that I can remember - and they only showed whiteboard of the code.  However, as I mentioned the teacher is a dev at JetBrains - so I should have figured it out.  Thank you.

Comment: All modern IDEs will have auto completion.

Comment: Of course, but as I said they showed only a whiteboard of code and no IDE, I am taking a course next that will use Emacs - so not everyone codes using a modern IDE, though.

Answer (score 1):

They mean "autocompletion", as in it will be shown when you put a `.` after an instance of the class being extended.

For example, typing `"myString".` will suggest the following extension function if it exists:

```
fun String.lastChar(): Char {
    return this.last()
}
```

However it would not suggest the following non-extension function:

```
fun lastChar(value: String): Char {
    return value.last()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the following code:

```
class X()

fun X.aaaa() {
    
}

val foo = X()

foo.aa
```

When you position the cursor after `foo` and type `.aa` in IntelliJ, you'll see the following context menu showing you that a method `aaaa` exists on the `foo` instance. You can press `Return` at this point to "autocomplete" the reference to that method.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2EaY.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsQCv.png]

Note that `aaaa()` is offered as an option (the only option)...as the one method available to you on your `foo` instance that starts with `aa`.  That's what it's talking about. `aaaa()` is shown as an available instance method even though it is defined as an extension function outside of the definition of `X` itself.